# Remove action in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I work on a wordpress theme with woocommerce.
I created a child theme and try to modify something in the function.php file.

I want to delete an action but i can't

I try to delete this action :

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_summary_details_open_2', 45 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_summary_details_open_2(){ global $product; ?>
                            <div class="summary-details">

                                <div class="et-accordion collapsible-false">

                                    <?php if ($product->get_short_description()): ?>
                                        <div class="accordion-title active"><?php echo esc_html__('Description','meow'); ?></div>
                                        <div class="accordion-content active"><?php echo meow_enovathemes_output_html($product->get_short_description()); ?></div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <?php if ($product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || 
                                        $product->has_dimensions() ) )): ?>
                                        <div class="accordion-title active"><?php echo esc_html__('Additional information','meow'); ?></div>
                                        <div class="accordion-content active"><?php wc_display_product_attributes( $product ) ?></div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                </div>

                        <?php }
```

normally i add something like that in my function.php in child theme and it's ok :

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action(){
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_summary_details_open_2', 45 );
}
```

But this time it's not ok and i don't know why. I think it's because this hook is in that :

```
     add_action('init',function(){


                    $shop_layout_single = get_theme_mod('shop_layout_single');
                    
                    $data_shop  = (isset($_GET["data_shop"]) && !empty($_GET["data_shop"])) ? $_GET["data_shop"] : "default";
                    if($data_shop == 'layout2' || $data_shop == 'sidebar2'){
                        $shop_layout_single = 'layout2';
                    }

                    if (empty($shop_layout_single)) {
                        $shop_layout_single = 'layout1';
                    }

                    if ($shop_layout_single == 'layout1') {

                        add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'meow_enovathemes_remove_product_tabs_info', 98 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_remove_product_tabs_info( $tabs ) {
                          unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // To remove the additional information tab
                          return $tabs;
                        }

                        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_summary_details_open_2', 45 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_summary_details_open_2(){ global $product; ?>
                            <div class="summary-details">

                                <div class="et-accordion collapsible-false">

                                    <?php if ($product->get_short_description()): ?>
                                        <div class="accordion-title active"><?php echo esc_html__('Description','meow'); ?></div>
                                        <div class="accordion-content active"><?php echo meow_enovathemes_output_html($product->get_short_description()); ?></div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <?php if ($product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || 
                                        $product->has_dimensions() ) )): ?>
                                        <div class="accordion-title active"><?php echo esc_html__('Additional information','meow'); ?></div>
                                        <div class="accordion-content active"><?php wc_display_product_attributes( $product ) ?></div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                </div>

                        <?php }

                        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_summary_details_close_2', 47 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_summary_details_close_2(){ ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php }

                        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_single_product_fbt', 5 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_single_product_fbt() {meow_enovathemes_fbt_output();}
                    } else {
                        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meow_enovathemes_single_product_fbt_summary', 45 );
                        function meow_enovathemes_single_product_fbt_summary() {meow_enovathemes_fbt_output();}
                    }

                });
```

I don't know but i think it's the first line which do something and broke my hook :

```
  add_action('init',function(){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these 3 things, maybe one of these will work:

1. `add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action', 9 );`
2. `add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action', 11 );`
3. `add_action( 'wp', 'remove_my_action' );`